# Удалить все файлы в каталоге кроме обьявленных

Tags: c#, файлы

приветствую. суть вопроса в заголовке. есть приложение которое каждый раз при входе сканирует папку на наличие лишних файлов. лишние это те которые не определены в list. собственно :

```
   private void DeleteFILES(DAL dal)
    {
        List<string> Equals = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dal.getMNamesfromBD().Count; i++)
        {
            Equals.Add(dal.getMNamesfromBD()[i].ToString());
        }
            try
        {
            string CompletePatchToEXE = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(CompletePatchToEXE + @"\\materials\\");
            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                for (int i=0; i<dal.getMNamesfromBD().Count; i++)
                {
                    if (file.Name != Equals[i]+ ".jpg")
                    {
                        file.Delete();
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Файлы поставленные в очереди были успешно удалены!", "Редактирование");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }
    }
```

однако вместо того что бы удалять файлы не прописанные в Equals код удаляет вообще все файлы. не могу найти ошибку, подскажите где исправить? спасибо!

Comment: Вот так `if (file.Name != Equals[i]+ ".jpg")` в цикле где одновременно действие писать нельзя. это и есть строка с ошибкой

Comment: Допустим первый елемент совпал - не удалили, но тогда второй елемент массива точно не совпадёт - и действие будет удалить.

Comment: блин! совсем упустил такой момент а ведь и правда.

Comment: Вы можете 1) использовать `List` и делать  `List.IndexOf() < 0` 2) использовать bool влаг, вмето delete в цикле делать `keepFile=true;` а после цикла `if (!keepFile) delete`

Comment: Не понял как IndexOf использовать. Он найдет индекс первого несовпадающего элемента и запретит сравнивать его с остальными в каталоге?

Comment: Найдя -1 вы будете знать что елемента его нету в списке, найдля число `>=0` вы будете знать что елемент есть в списке. И можно будет убрать цикл проверки. (Но тогда будет цикл который наполнит список)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код можно сильно упростить, используя LINQ.

Также освойте метод [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) для работы с путями файловой системы.

```
var materialsDirectory = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "materials");

List<string> Equals = // заполняем список из БД

var distinct = Directory.GetFiles(materialsDirectory)
    .Except(Equals.Select(s => Path.Combine(materialsDirectory, s, ".jpg")));

foreach (var fileName in distinct)
    new FileInfo(fileName).Delete();
```

Если я правильно понял, в списке только названия файлов без полного пути и без расширения.

P. S. Судя по другим вашим вопросам, папка materials используется во многих местах кода. Поэтому добавьте поле формы, куда занесите нужный путь один раз при старте приложения, а далее просто используйте его.